# Best Data Type to Store Result of HASHBYTES('MD5', ...)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datatypes, hashing

What would be the best data type to store the results of the `HASHBYTES('MD5', ...)`?

It outputs 16 bytes of binary as follows: e.g.

```
0x5CFCD77F9FF836189D2F647EBCEA183E
```

I could store it in the following data types:

- `char(34)`
- `binary(16)` (I think - I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722305/what-kind-of-datatype-should-one-use-to-store-hashes#16680423) that using the same algo should return the same number of bytes every time regardless of the input string)
- other?

Every row will have a value (no nulls), and the column will be used for comparison against a similar column in another table.

Which is the best data type to store `HASHBYTES` output for use as described above?

I was thinking that since fixed length data types can sometimes be more efficient on joins, etc. `binary(16)` vs `varbinary(8000)` (the default output of `HASHBYTES`) seems best, and `binary(16)` vs a `varchar(34)` is better since it would use less storage space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Books Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql):

> The output conforms to the algorithm standard: 128 bits (16 bytes) for
>   MD2, MD4, and MD5; 160 bits (20 bytes) for SHA and SHA1; 256 bits (32
>   bytes) for SHA2_256, and 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA2_512.

So despite the fact that the function technically returns varbinary(8000), you'll only ever get 16 bytes with MD5. If you are completely certain you only need MD5, then a binary(16) will do it. If you want to play it safe, and allow any possible algorithm (current or future) that HASHBYTES can handle, go with varbinary(8000).

I definitely wouldn't recommend a char type, since that will involve string conversion overhead, and unnecessary storage overhead.